# Retrieving Database Compatibility Level - Different Result for Same Server/DB, Different Users

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have the following code to determine a SQL Server database's compatibility level:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Server(myServerName);
if (!server.Databases.Contains(database)) 
  { throw new ArgumentException("Specified database ('" + myDBName+ "') not found on '" + myServerName + "'"); }

string connstr = string.Format("Data Source={0};" +
   "Persist Security Info=False;" +
   "User ID={1};" +
   "Password={2};Enlist=False;", myServerName, username, password);
server.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString = connstr;

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database db = server.Databases[myDBName];
DataSet ds = db.ExecuteWithResults(@"select compatibility_level 
           from sys.databases where name=db_name()");
```

I have two users, one of which is able to run this code and get the proper value back. Another user runs this code connecting to the same Server/Database with the exact same credentials and the DataSet returned contains no rows.

What could possibly be the difference between the two users that would cause one to get no result back for the same query?  Is there a better way to get Database compatibility?

By the way, this code runs/works on SQL Server 2005 through 2012.

**Edit:** I should have pointed out that myServerName, myDBName, username, and password are always the same--the only difference is the two different Windows users running the code.

Comment: Does adding myDBName to the connection string as the `Initial Catalog` or `Database` change your results?  That would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: @RThomas: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I did try it with the DBName.  Same result.  I even tried it in the select in place of db_name().

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the user who returns results has the VIEW_ANY_DEFINITON permission granted to his login. Grant this permission to the other user and he should get the results back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Pete. On a test machine, I specifically denied VIEW_ANY_DEFINITION. This caused more problems as my check to see if the db exists (sorry, added that after your answer) always fails. In fact, it pretty much cripples the connection.